# Extract duplicate values from all the column of csv file by using python

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which have **one unique column (id)** and 7 other columns(C1) consists of classes that is related with the one unique column. Now i want to **extract only duplicate data from 7 columns** 
but i actually need to code something like what output is.

Example:

```
**id C1   C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7**  
P1   a1   a2    a4  
P2   a2         a4    a6  a7  
P3                 a5     a7  
P4   a1         a3
```

**output**

```
a1=> P1, P4  
a2=>P1, P2  
a3=>P4  
a4=>P1, P2  
a5=>P3  
and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stack` with `groupby`

```
df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index().groupby(0).id.apply(list)
Out[137]: 
0
a1    [P1, P4]
a2    [P1, P2]
a3        [P4]
a4    [P1, P2]
a5        [P3]
a6        [P2]
a7    [P2, P3]
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: WOW  my file name is go.csv can you share a code how to read it and then apply above process. sorry i am newbie

Comment: Thanks it worked now if i want to retrieve only most frequent classes what i will add e.g most frequent is P1 and P2 only

Comment: @user3768070 you can do value count : `value_counts`  Like 


`df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index().groupby(0).id.apply(list).astype(str).value_counts()`